# JavaScript & Checkboxes - More efficient way of storing values of each checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Is there a more efficient way of storing my checkbox values?

Each checkbox has an assigned value, I was wondering if there was a better way of storing these values (destinationoflink1,2,3,etc)? perhaps store them as an array and call them?...although I am unsure

HTML page extract:

```
    <form>
        <label for="checkbox1">Link #1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="http://www.destinationoflink1.com">
        <label for="checkbox2">Link #2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="http://www.destinationoflink2.com">
        <label for="checkbox3">Link #3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="http://www.destinationoflink3.com">

        <input type="button" value="open links" id="open_link"/>
    </form>
```

Javascript file extract (if useful):

```
$("#open_link").click(function() {
    performOpenLink();
})

function performOpenLink(){
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            window.open(this.value)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate your checkboxes dynamically using an array

**Modified HTML**

```
<form>
    <div id="checkbox_container"></div>    
    <input type="button" value="open links" id="open_link"/>
</form>
```

---

**Modified JavaScript**

```
var destinations = [
    {'label': 'Checkbox1', 'value' : 'http://www.destinationoflink1.com'},
    {'label': 'Checkbox2', 'value' : 'http://www.destinationoflink2.com'},
    {'label': 'Checkbox3', 'value' : 'http://www.destinationoflink3.com'}
];

$(function(){
    // document onReady

    for (var i=0; i<destinations.length; i++){
        // add the label:
        $('#checkbox_container').append('<label for="' + destinations[i].label + '">Link #' + i + '</label>');

        // add the checkbox:
        $('#checkbox_container').append('<input type="checkbox" id="'+ destinations[i].label+'" value="' + destinations[i].value + '" >');
    }
});

$("#open_link").click(function() {
    performOpenLink();
});

function performOpenLink(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            window.open(this.value)
        }
    });
}
```

---

This will loop through the array and build the `label` and `checklist` html based on properties of each array item. By placing the values into an array, it should be easier for you to add (or remove) new Checklist values later

Here's a <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thqLexnx/4/)</kbd>

---

Update: I fixed the issue where I left `this` in the code. Replaced with `destinations[i]`

Comment: Thank you! This is along the lines of what I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach...

```
$("#open_link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.each($("input[type=checkbox]:checked"), function(index, item){
        window.open( item.value, index );
    });
});
```

and this is the ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3g9eshsL/1/)***

It doesn't open multiple tabs in chrome, but it works perfectly in firefox(v38.0 for me)..

Comment: It's an ad block/pop up blocker issue, but that's something else I need to figure out how to fix :S